# How to make a call on button click in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have done the following code inside of my getView() method  of CustomAdapter class. If I try to simply show a Toast, Toast appears, but if i do the following code to make a call, application crashes. What i am doing wrong here?

```
                call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone.getText().toString()));
                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });
```

and the stacktrace shows this error :

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.hammad.contactme, PID: 26713 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

Comment: did you get the correct permission for making call in **Manifest** and Run time if you are one Android 6+ ?

Comment: Permission added. It doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work for ACTION_DIAL too.

Comment: You need to look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the exact cause of the crash.

Comment: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that detail. Anyway, it sounds like you got your `context` from `getApplicationContext()`. Make sure to use the `Activity` when instantiating your `Adapter`, not get `getApplicationContext()`. This will also ensure that the inflated `View`s have the correct theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the correct permission for making call in **AndroidManifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

and if you are running on android 6.0 or above you should also get this permission on runtime

[getting runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: both runtime and manifest ?!
can you add your error stack trace ?

Comment: can you add your stack trace ?

Comment: Is this a problem?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.hammad.contactme, PID: 26713
                                                                              android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: add `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` to your intent see if that helps

Comment: happy to help ;)